# Angular how to make smooth X scroll on hover (auto)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `component` which has gallery with `X axis`.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div (mouseenter)="scrollTo('left', $event)" (mouseleave)="clearIntervalRepeater()" class="left"></div>
    <div (mouseenter)="scrollTo('right', $event)"  (mouseleave)="clearIntervalRepeater()" class="right"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div #sidewayScroller class="sideway">
            <img *ngFor="let item of galleryImages" [src]="item" alt="gallery-image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have two `divs` inside "left" and "right" , they are transparent absolute divs, which are used only for hover to affect `#sidewayScroller`.

I am trying ot achieve smooth scroll on hover to the side "left" or "right".

**My hover function :**

```
  scrollTo(position, event: HTMLElement){
    if(position == 'left'){
      console.log('left');
      this.repeater = setInterval(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.scrollTo({
          left: this.el.nativeElement.scrollLeft - 200,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        })
      }, 150);
    } else {
      this.repeater = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('right');
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollTo({
        left: this.el.nativeElement.scrollLeft + 200,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    }, 180);
    }
  }

  clearIntervalRepeater(){
    console.log('clearing');
    clearInterval(this.repeater);
  }
```

**Problem**, it's not smooth, it goes with gliches. I want that it would be smooth but I can't get that interval, can someone help me to calculate it or try another method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the scroll behavior. Scroll behavior will scroll smooth to the set position but then stops and has to start on again. Setting the scroll position manually and lowering the interval and the steps for better framerate should fix your problem:

```
scrollTo(position, event: MouseEvent){
    if(position == 'left'){
      console.log('left');
      this.repeater = setInterval(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 5;
      }, 10);
    } else {
      this.repeater = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('right');
        this.el.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 5;
      }, 10);
    }
}
```

Now the movements speed is constant and it looks smooth.